# Pattern.compile For Multiple Email Address

Tags: java

I'm new to Java and I want to check if multiple domain names for emails match. This code works fine.

```
Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z0-9\\.\\-_]+@example1\\.com");
```

But how can I add second domain name to this code?

example:

```
Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z0-9\\.\\-_]+@example1\\.com+@example2\\.com");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may add the second domain using the OR option:

```
Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z0-9\\.\\-_]+@(example1\\.com|domain1\\.com)");
```